# Docker-compose link external/ local mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, pip, docker-compose

I have problem that unable to connect with my localhost mysql.

DockerFile

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME HelloWorld
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python app.py
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

requirement.txt

```
SQLAlchemy == 1.1.14
python_dateutil == 2.4.2
requests == 2.10.0
tornado == 4.4.2
```

When I type the command in terminal:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

It occur the error that said “No module named mysql” 
Should I include "mysql" in requirement.txt file or teach me how to link with the local mysql. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much depends on the nature of the application. If it requires MySQL — yes, include `mysql` in `requirements.txt`.

If it doesn't require MySQL but MySQL is required for the docker container install `mysql`:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip install mysql
```

Comment: I added the one command in Dockerfile
    RUN pip install mysql, but it occur error:      

    Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qb_0xy/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Comment: `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`. See the updated answer.